# MSDN Light Version

Tags: c#, msdn

Does anyone know if there is a light version of the MSDN Library for download? In other words, a version that is not 2GB..1GB Max

In response to some of you...only reason I care is because its for a programming competition and we can bring up to 2GB of data...MSDN breaks that

Comment: Hehe, every other word removed?

Comment: I wish there was also a Universe Lite™... I feel the world is currently a little too huge.

Comment: @Hans : could remove all the vowels

Comment: @Mitch: Idk about you, but that'd be a bit heavy on my ear...

Comment: haha..just about 3/4 of the words in msdn are useless anyways...but i mean it would be nice to just have the core libraries that most people use..leaving out things like gui...lol idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no light/minimalistic version of MSDN available for download. If it is of any interest, however, the only version offer a light online version for low bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

The most you can get is a [loband](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default%28loband%29.aspx) version of MSDN available online only. After all, who cares if it is 1 or 2 GB? Computers these days are a little bit better than calculators. You can get 8 GB flash drive for like couple dollars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the 2 GB download you could use the online version.

If you are not continuously online run the local install and pick only the content that you are interested in.

If you can't download at all, [get a DVD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff769488.aspx)